# Unusual error in Eclipse on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I am using this code to test if my Eclipse is working fine with OpenCV or not.

```
#include "opencv.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    IplImage* img = cvCreateImage( cvSize( 640, 480 ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 );

    cvCircle( img, cvPoint( 320, 240 ), 100, cvScalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 5 );

    cvNamedWindow( "OpenCV Window", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL );
    cvShowImage( "OpenCV Window", img );

    cvWaitKey(0);

    cvDestroyWindow( "OpenCV Window" );
    cvReleaseImage( &img );

    return 0;
}
```

Now when I build and run it once done with all the formalities of linking with OpenCV Libraries, I get the desired output.

*But when I run the project, in the error log it says `String index out of range:-7`, multiple times!*
*The plug-in it uses is `org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core`*

Is there a way I can resolve this and other errors of such kind?
Thanks in advance! :)

**EDIT:** It runs smoothly, as it should, but also generates these errors in the Error Log.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say you "execute it once done [...] you get the desired output." But when you "run" the project, there are errors? What is the difference?

Comment: @moswald: I have edited the question as per your requirements. Sorry, that was my bad!

Comment: btw, you should no more use opencv's deprecated c-api. discard that way of coding immediately in favour of cv::Mat, functions from the cv:: namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The "Error Log" is not a log of errors for *your* software, it is a log of errors for *eclipse*. The org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core plugin itself experienced some sort of error.  Unless the error is causing some sort of noticeable problem with your eclipse experience, you can safely ignore it.  I typically close that view down entirely unless I am experiencing issues with eclipse.

Warnings and error for your software will be displayed in the "Problems" view.